# PostgreSQL part of a string is in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get values for which part of their ids is in a defined list. Let's say that we have a table called `ABC`

```
CREATE TABLE abc
AS
  SELECT post_id
  FROM ( VALUES 
    ( '868164246578472_912876412107255' ),
    ( '868164246578472_912883258773237' ),
    ( '868164246578472_913049595423270' )
  ) AS t(post_id);
```

Then I just take a part after the underscore

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(element_id, '_'))[2] as element_id from ABC limit 3;
        element_id     
    -----------------
     912876412107255
     912883258773237
     913049595423270
```

Now I want to take only those elements, where their element_ids are in a defined list yet I get no results

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(post_id, '_'))[2] as post_id from ABC where post_id = ANY('{912876412107255, 912883258773237}'::text[]) limit 3;
 post_id 
---------
(0 rows)
```

I also tried this:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(post_id, '_'))[2]::text[] as post_id from ABC where post_id IN ('912876412107255', '912876412107255') limit 3;
 post_id 
---------
(0 rows)
```

The structure of the table is as follows:

```
Table "public.ABC"
    Column     |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
---------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('ABC_id_seq'::regclass)
 element_id    | text                        | not null
```

Comment: Why are you using the column alias in the where clause? (did not think that was allowed)
Also, why are you putting the selected expression into an array when there will only be 1 element.

Comment: @JoeLove: it is not allowed. And this why it fails for Godric.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I figured it out and immediately posted the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html) which is much cheaper than the regex function.

You should use the expression in WHERE clause:

```
select (string_to_array(post_id, '_'))[2] as post_id
from abc
where (string_to_array(post_id, '_'))[2] = any('{912876412107255, 912883258773237}');
```

or a derived table:

```
select post_id
from (
    select (string_to_array(post_id, '_'))[2] as post_id
    from abc
    ) s
where post_id = any('{912876412107255, 912883258773237}');
```

A derived table does not generate additional costs, the queries are equivalent.

---

Update. The function `split_part()` even better suits your query:

```
select split_part(post_id, '_', 2) as post_id
from abc
where split_part(post_id, '_', 2) = any('{912876412107255, 912883258773237}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested (from my phone):

```
SELECT kmkid, element_id
    FROM (SELECT (regexp_split_to_array(element_id, '_'))[2] as kmkid, element_id FROM ABC)
    WHERE kmkid IN ('912876412107255', '912876412107255');
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick note, the problem here is that you have two values serialized inside the same field. This is bad. If you're doing this it's because those values are different.

What you should do instead is break them apart, or if they are a list store them as an array.

```
ALTER TABLE abc
  ALTER COLUMN post_Id
  SET DATA TYPE numeric[] USING ( string_to_array(post_Id, '_')::numeric[] );
```

Now, you can query on foo directly if any of those fields are equal

```
SELECT * FROM abc
WHERE post_id @> ARRAY[912876412107255::numeric];
```

Or if one of them is

```
SELECT * FROM abc
WHERE post_id[2] = 912876412107255::numeric;
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, I've just found the answer:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(element_id, '_'))[2] as element_id from ABC where element_id similar to '%(912876412107255|912883258773237)%';
     element_id     
-----------------
 912876412107255
 912883258773237
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Add a `_` and remove the trailing `%` to get less spurious matches. You can still get some if some `element_id` happen to be the prefix of the ones you want. An ugly solution to sum it up.

Comment: Avoid regex functions when they are not necessary. Simple string manipulation functions are cheaper (faster).

Comment: Also the whole SIMILAR TO is stupid. It's always slower than a regex. And, you know what the entire ID is. So why use `%` after you've split it out?